# Restrict a document path from Backend in Sitefinity site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, sitefinity-5

I need to add a Restrict on a document file path accessed from Sitefinity if there is no value in session.
I have an URL to documents stored in CMS like below

> "~/docs/default-source/documentlibraryname/documentname.doc"

I Need to do some restriction in code when I try to access any direct path from Sitefinity.

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
  var virtualPath = base.GetVirtualPathInternal(httpContext);
}
```

It's only giving `~/favicon.icon` in `virtualPath` so cant get specific URL. I have tried **Httphandler** and also **SitefinityRoute** implementations for the same.

If anyone has any suggestions please help.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to just set the Permissions on this document for Authenticated users for instance?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is a path accessible by anyone who is not a backend user.